# Security.yml - State_id

Tags: security, session, symfony

I do log in the user very well. It is working fine in symfony2. During registration in the DB the role and a state_id are going to be saved.

```
role: ROLE_USER
state_id: 4  //e.g. has only permissions to do some extra actions
```

Is there a way in symfony2 in the security.yml that I give permissions to targets with role and state_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use different roles for this, not a state id. For example: `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_USER_4`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I thought so. But I wasn't sure! Thanks again!

Comment: And don't forget that you can use [role hierarchy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles), so `ROLE_USER_4` role will also have the `ROLE_USER` role, but with some extra actions